# Get printers connected/available

Tags: c#, .net, printing

Running the following code I get always nothing for "Availability".
How can I get information if a printer is online or offline? In Windows settings it is shown but not by my code:

```
    {        
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
        scope.Connect();

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

        foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get())
        {
            string printerName = printer["Name"].ToString().ToLower();
            Console.WriteLine("Printer :" + printerName);

            PrintProps(printer, "Caption");
            PrintProps(printer, "ExtendedPrinterStatus");
            PrintProps(printer, "Availability");
            PrintProps(printer, "Default");
            PrintProps(printer, "DetectedErrorState");
            PrintProps(printer, "ExtendedDetectedErrorState");
            PrintProps(printer, "ExtendedPrinterStatus");
            PrintProps(printer, "LastErrorCode");
            PrintProps(printer, "PrinterState");
            PrintProps(printer, "PrinterStatus");
            PrintProps(printer, "Status");
            PrintProps(printer, "WorkOffline");
            PrintProps(printer, "Local");
        }
    }

    static void PrintProps(ManagementObject o, string prop)
    {
        try { Console.WriteLine(prop + "|" + o[prop]); }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.Write(e.ToString()); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that one have to differentiate between network/wlan connected printers and usb wired printers:

```
   PrintProps(printer, "WorkOffline"); // works only for usb wired printers
```